# regexp in mysql - find a string that holds ALL keywords (AND operator)

Tags: mysql, regex, syntax, keyword

I am stuck for 3 hours with i guess simple thing but been searching internet and didnt find the answer. 
I have 1, 2, 3, 4 or more keywords and a string to search for keywords in it. I am looking for regexp expression that maches ALL the keywords. So for example:

string = "this car is red and has big wheels"

keywords: **car wheels**

return: true

keywords: **wheels car**

return: true

keywords: **car is red**

return: true

keywords: **this is big**

return: true

keywords: **car is red small**

return: false (there is no 'small' word in string)

I use such a mysql query:

```
SELECT name, desc FROM table WHERE CONCAT(name, desc) REGEXP ($keyword1)($keyword2)
```

But it returns empty string. What should be correct regexp syntax?

Comment: What's the calling language? PHP?

Comment: Regular expressions in MySQL don't support back-references, so you'd need to explicitly spell out every possible order: `[[:<:]]keyword1[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]keyword2[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]keyword2[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]keyword1[[:>:]]`.  It's not pretty.

Comment: @minitech: yes, i use php 5.3

Comment: eggyal: definately no pretty - i was looking for more elegant way without dozens of WHERE LIKEs ... i guess there is no "more elegant way"

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to move the `AND` out of regexp and into SQL:

```
SELECT name, desc
FROM table
WHERE CONCAT(name, desc) REGEXP ($keyword1)
  AND CONCAT(name, desc) REGEXP ($keyword2)
```

Otherwise, your regexp would have to include all `N!` possible orders in a long chain of `OR` statements, and that length grows very, very fast (with 5 keywords, you'd need to construct 120 distinct orderings!)

Comment: but in this case i do not have use REGEXP - i can use LIKE %keyword1 AND ... i hoped that i can do it more elegant way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kalreg Absolutely, using `LIKE %keyword1%` would be preferred.