# MySQL Query multiple keywords searching in long string using Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Example keyword search "CAR WASH"
car wash have to be appear in the string regardless of position

The searchable string can be very long and the query should search for these keywords together and separately. There can be more than two keywords.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE zip LIKE'abc'";
$key= explode(" ", $keywords);
for($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++){
    $query.=" AND (dealTitle LIKE '".$key[$i]." %' OR dealTitle LIKE '% ".$key[$i]." %' OR dealTitle LIKE '% ".$key[$i]." ')";
    }
```

However, the query is returning those records containing "car" **or** "wash".

If I use "car wash" both words need to appear at least once. Any suggestion on how to modify my search to take this condition into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++){
        $query.=" AND (dealTitle rlike '[[:<:]]".$key[$i]."[[:>:]]' )";
}
```

Should use AND

EDITED:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++){
            $query.=" AND (dealTitle like '% ".$key[$i]." %' or dealTitle like '% ".$key[$i]."' or dealTitle like '".$key[$i]."%') ";
    }
```

Comment: same problem it will accept the keyword "CARD" also along with the car

Comment: it would return the keyword "CAR" if the wash isnt in the string??

Comment: what you want is car wash have to be appear in the string regardless of position, am i understand it correctly?

Comment: to cater an exact string, use `[[:<:]]car[[:>:]]`. Amended my answer and pls try. In this case, will return only result with car and wash together appear in the string since using `AND`.

Comment: `[[:<:]]` denotes the start of the word and `[[:>:]]` denotes end of the word.

Comment: its working one of my friend said that it will be costy on DB and will degarde performance a lot in live load envoirent
better simply use like statement of db

Comment: You could try my edited answer.Btw, i think that is same with your existing query then?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using mysql database, there is a full text search functionality which will be robust and scalable solution.

```
$query .= " AND MATCH(dealTitle) AGAINST('". $searchString ."')";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

Look into this article to understand FULLTEXT SEARCH function in MySQL.

Comment: here is the error   #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Comment: So it is possible to introduce FULLTEXT index over this column?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   AND (CONCAT(' ',dealTitle,' ') LIKE '% car %' and 
   CONCAT(' ',dealTitle,' ') LIKE '% wash %' )
```

Comment: it will return me the card also.. this is not accepted keyword one more question here same [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414586/regexp-in-mysql-find-a-string-that-holds-all-keywords-and-operator

Comment: what about the second keyword at the start.. ?? like "WASH CAR"

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :-

```
AND (dealTitle LIKE '%car wash%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to achieve what a search engine does -- full-text indexing.   `LIKE '%keyword%'` is partial match as you already know.  Not only it hits partial word, it is very slow because the db has to read and compare each one of records on the disk.

Consider using full-text indexer.  MySQL specifically supports it.  See [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)